# How to restrict user from same Username and Password to logic from two system/browser in asp.net mvc 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I've created a asp.net mvc4 web site. I've implemented Form authentication also.
In this web site i want to block access to my web site client in a same time (if a client of my website is already open his or her account in a computer then that client can not get any permission to open that same website on the same time in other computer or any other browser of the same system).

I want to provide one paid service to user, and I don't want him to just share his username and password with many people to use my service simultaneously without paying for it. please help me soon

How can I implement this. do i need to maintain some login information in database or is there any built in tool available for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not built in.

I would add an "IsLoggedIn" bit column to my "User" table.  Then you could check this column to see if the user should be allowed in.

The problem is going to be knowing when that flag should be set to false.  It's easy enough to set the flag to false if the user clicks "logout" or in the "on session end" event, but I think you'll run in to cases where that's not good enough.  For example, if a user logs in from a laptop and the laptop's battery fails, you aren't going to get any notification from the client that the user has left...

Comment: what if user just closes their browser without clicking logout button, how can i change that field in table? How to tackle with this situation?

Comment: I want to provide one paid service to user, and I don't want him to just share his username and password with many people to use my service simultaneously without paying for it. please help me soon.

Comment: I think with this solution you'll end up with lots of locked out users - you need to allow the ability for a user to login again and invalidate their __previous__ session, not stop them from creating a new session.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there is nothing built in, but you may be able to implement your own version of the [ASP.NET authorization providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Upon successful login you would need to store the value of the [FormsAuthenticationTicket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your database and associate it to your user record.

On every page load you would need to check the value of the ticket against the database record for that user. In case of mismatch the user would be logged out.

Using this approach if User A and User B were using the same credentials, User A was logged in and if User B then logged in, it would invalidate User A's session and they would not be able to view content at the same time. You could also log the activity when a session is overridden, along with IP address and User Agent to help you identify users that are sharing account details.

Comment: @Silverfox On every page_load, doesn't this will increase server trips ?

Comment: @SurajSingh Yes, you'd need a query on every page load if you were using a database. Ideally tokens should be validated anyway, otherwise users that have had their password changed by another session would remain logged in (not good if your account had been compromised and you wanted to make sure you account is now secure). This is of course a trade off of security vs performance.

Comment: (+1)Just confused about it, Can we achieve this using session-state?

Comment: @SurajSingh No, because session state is unique to each browser session. You could possibly achieve this using Application state though as that is global to all users on __the current server__. Depends if you have a load balanced cluster or single machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think **David** has already given most of the idea (+1) , However for problems like closing browser without logging out, You can handle it in `window.unload()` event for setting the flag in your table .

Comment: That would be very hit and miss because you're limited to either a popup which would be blocked, or an AJAX request that wouldn't be guaranteed to be executed before the browser has navigated away.